# socket is not blocking on write operation: OpenSolaris

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, tcp, solaris, nonblocking

I have a unit test that checks behavior on blocking and non-blocking sockets - the server writes a long response and at some point it should not be able to write any more and it
blocks on write.

Basically one side writes and other side does not reads.

Under Solaris at some point I get a error "Not enough space" (after writing 75MB) instead of blocking on write:

Program that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

char const *address = "127.0.0.1";
#define check(x) do { if( (x) < 0) { perror(#x) ; exit(1); } } while(0)

int main()
{
    signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN);
    struct sockaddr_in inaddr = {};
    inaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
    inaddr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    int res = fork();
    if(res < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(res > 0) {
        int fd = -1;
        int status;
        sleep(1);   
        check(fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0));
        check(connect(fd,(sockaddr*)&inaddr,sizeof(inaddr)));
        sleep(5);
        close(fd);

        wait(&status);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int acc,fd;
        check(acc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0));
        int yes = 1;
        check(setsockopt(acc,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(yes)));
        check(bind(acc,(sockaddr*)&inaddr,sizeof(inaddr)));
        check(listen(acc,10));
        check(fd = accept(acc,0,0));

        char buf[1000];
        long long total= 0;
        do {
            int r = send(fd,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
            if(r < 0) {
                printf("write %s\n",strerror(errno));
                return 0;
            }
            else if(r==0) {
                printf("Got eof\n");
                return 0;
            }
            total += r;
            if(total > 100*1024*1024) {
                printf("Too much!!!!\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("%lld\n",total);
        }while(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The output on Solaris (last two lines)

```
75768000
write Not enough space
```

The expected output on Linux (last two lines)

```
271760
write Connection reset by peer
```

Which happens only when the other side closes the socket.

Any ideas why and how can I fix it, what options to set?

P.S.: It is OpenSolaris 2009.06, x86

**Edits**

- Added full C code that reproduces the problem

**Answer:**

This seems like a bug in specific version of Solaris kernel, libc library.

Comment: are you sure send doesn't return partial completion? it is not in your sample code.

Comment: @bazsi77 Partial completion is ok first of all and 2nd it is not it always succeeds to write full chunks

Comment: I know it is OK, I was just wondering if the code handled that case correctly. But then, if you can send so much data, it must be stored somewhere. On Linux, netstat is able to display the buffered amount. Also, system memory use must increase. If it does, it really seems to be a bug in the kernel, in which case I'd file a bugreport, or try to locate the problem in the OpenSolaris kernel code.

Comment: @bazsi77 The code I provided is very schematic, under the hood it does much more

Comment: I've checked the related OpenSolaris code, and as it seems the kernel will only make the socket unwritable if the send buffer is full (SO_SNDBUF). Any chance tcp_xmit_hiwat was tuned on your system. That kernel tunable seems to control the default SO_SNDBUF size. And if that value is extreme, that could potentially explain your problem.

Comment: @bazsi77 I'll check this `tcp_xmit_hiwat` option also I've tried setting `SO_SNDBUF` on sender's side and `SO_RCVBUF` on the reader's side to a small size, but it had no effect I was still able to write many megabytes without blocking.

Comment: Well, it must be a bug in your specific version then. I was checking the code available in the CVS, the other guy who posted the first answer says he couldn't reproduce it. So try with a newer release. This behaviour is clearly buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OpenSolaris source code, I'm afraid the SO_SNDTIMEO option is unsupported: https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/inet/sockmods/socksctp.c#l1233

Comment: strange because setsockopt succeeds and according to the code you linked it should fail. Also it seems it is not supported in getsockopt not setsockopt. Additionally, in asynchronous code that does not use this option it failes as well.

Comment: setsockopt "supports" SO_SNDTIMEO in the sense it accepts whatever value is passed but it does nothing with it. I just tested your updated code on Solaris 11 Express and the writing process blocks on write after 140kBytes. It finally got a broken pipe error (but you ignore it) after the listening process close the socket and the next write complete.

Comment: in the sample above now I don't use `SO_SNDTIMEO` at all. BTW I don't ignore broken pipe I block it, otherwise the process would just exit. I get the error on socket.

Comment: thanks for this information. I think I'll have to update my code... (this is really not nice that Solaris ignores this option)

Comment: It seems to me you are ignoring, not blocking, the broken pipe in your sample code : `signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN);` Blocking would imply using sigprocmask.

Comment: I see, in any case it does the job. In any case I don't want signal to be delivered but rather reported on socket.

Comment: Accepting this as the fact that `SO_SNDTIMEO` is not supported was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block if there's no space available, you need to write code to do that.
POSIX is pretty clear that `write` on a socket is equivalent to `send` with no options, and that `send` "[may fail if ... [i]nsufficient resources were available in the system to perform the operation.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/send.html)"